# Websockets support on Openshift

Tags: openshift

This [article](https://blog.openshift.com/paas-websockets/) was back in 2012.  And it has not been updated.  Any idea what is current websockets support in particularly PHP cartridge?

Comment: Can you be more specific with your question?  Maybe list some specific information that you are looking for.

Comment: @developercorey: There was this statement: "We are releasing a preview version of WebSockets support"  It was back in 2012.  And there was not mentioning anything about PHP.  Googling does not seem to return much about this.  Any pointers for PHP would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current webscoket support is the same as outlined in [the mentioned blog post](https://blog.openshift.com/paas-websockets/), only it's no longer the *preview version*. [This diagram](https://developers.openshift.com/managing-your-applications/port-binding-routing.html) reflects the present situation.